# A problem of showing a matrix is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Suppose,  $A$ be a $2×2$ real matrix with $tr(A) =0$ and $det(A) =-1. $ Then show that :

$(a)$ $\mathbb R^2$ has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A .$

$(b)$ Suppose, $T$ be the real matrix wrt the above basis $\beta$ such that $TA = AT.$ Prove that, $T$ is a diagonal matrix wrt that basis.

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1 .$ Then, $A$ is diagonalisable and hence part $(a)$ is done . Name that ordered basis $\beta =\{v_1,v_2\}  .$

Then, wrt the basis $\beta$, the matrix of  $T$ be
$T = \begin{pmatrix}
                                   x & z \\
                                   y & w \\   
                               \end{pmatrix}$
where $v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
                                   x \\
                                   y  \\   
                               \end{pmatrix}$ ; and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
                                   z \\
                                   w  \\   
                               \end{pmatrix}$ such that $Av_1 = v_1$ and $Av_2 = -v_2$, then we get, $TA = AT =\begin{pmatrix}
                                                x & -z \\
                                                y & -w \\   
                                               \end{pmatrix}$; then we can get some system of equations, but how to show that $T$ is diagonal ???

A little help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $T$ be a real matrix wrt the above basis mean?

Comment: I have edited the question;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_{-1}, v_1$ be the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues
$\lambda_{-1} = -1, \lambda_1 = 1$. Note that $\ker (A -\lambda_k I)$ is one
dimensional.

Note that $A T v_k = TA v_k = \lambda_k T v_k$ and so $T v_k \in \ker (A -\lambda_k I)$.
In particular, $Tv_k = \beta_k v_k$.

Hence in the basis $v_{-1},v_1$ we see that $T$ has the form $\operatorname{diag}(\beta_{-1}, \beta_1)$.